# how to design application UI for all resolutions in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am working on android application for my embedded project and I am very new to android.
I have developed UI which should be suitable for all kind of screens (all resolution) in android.

Below is my code for all kind of resolution:

```
      if ( ((width>=240)&&(width<=320))&&((height>=320)&&(height<=480)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.xsmall_layout);
    }
    else if( ((width>=360)&&(width<=480))&&((height>=640)&&(height<=720)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.small_layout);
    }
    else if ( ((width>=480)&&(width<=540))&&((height>720)&&(height<=960)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.medium_layout);
    }
    else if ( ((width>540)&&(width<=800))&&((height>=1024)&&(height<=1280)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.vlarger_layout);        
    }
    else if ( ((width>800)&&(width<=1080))&&((height>=1280)&&(height<=1920)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.x_vlarger_layout);
    }
    else if ( ((width>=800)&&(width<=1024))&&((height>=480)&&(height<600)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.wlarger_layout);
    }
    else if ( ((width>=1024)&&(width<=1280))&&((height>=600)&&(height<=800)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.x_wlarger_layout);
    }
    else if ( ((width>=1280)&&(width<=2560))&&((height>800)&&(height<=1600)) )
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.xx_wlarger_layout);
    }
```

Its working fine, but is it a good practice ?
And in my pc(Intel Dual core, 2GB RAM), for the last resolution in the code is not working.
I tried 1920x1200 and 2560x1600 . Android emulator is only not running. 
simply its coming black screen.
Is this my PC problem or what..?
Help me seniors......

Comment: Why aren't you using the different layout folders?

Comment: try : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you can create different layout folder inside your `res` folder like:

```
layout-land
layout-large
layout-large-land
layout-xlarge
layout-xlarge-land
```

Keep the name of xml layout file same in every folder but you can mention different dimensions value.

Anyway, here is the test case you can do:

1. Create a folder layout-large
2. copy main.xml file and paste inside layout-large folder
3. Change text size of TextView with some random values.
4. Load app inside different density emulators. Enjoy !!

Comment: Hi Paresh Mayani, ya i tried that also.And I have also added the <supports-screens> in Manifest for all type of screens. But I am getting error. Main activity is not finding the layouts if I copied to the particular folders.So I implemented like this.

Comment: @Mars7285 show your layout folders snap. One more thing give the same name to XML layout file in each folders.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this one:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In this Documentation they have clearly explained about all supporting screen resolution and dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mars try like this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Here they created these layout folders inside res

and puted same `xml` file to each layout:

```
layout


         layout-small
                        layout-large
                                         layout-xlarge
```

this thing ll take care for screen size.

i.e for table,smartphones etc

Comment: Hi Cobra, ya i tried that also.And I have also added the <supports-screens> in Manifest for all type of screens. But I am getting error. Main activity is not finding the layouts if I copied to the particular folders.So I implemented like this.

Comment: no need to put in manifest file dud. just make these folder and put your main.xml in these folder.